# Are "in the game" and "on the game" interchangeable?

Tags: prepositions

I have searched some examples from the web:

Some examples from the web:

1. I got money on this game.
2. I have three million on this game.
3. There must be thousands of dollars bet on this game.
4. Besides, I got a lot of money riding on this game.
5. Does he have money on this game or something?

And some others:

1. Trust is everything in this game.
2. Such conduct is not allowed in this game.
3. There are no more levels in this game.
4. I'm not going to get hurt in this game.

Looks like they are all the same. Does that mean "in the game" and "on the game" are interchangeable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your examples are not 'all the same'. The second group refer to actually playing the game, the first are all about betting money on the result of the game. I wouldn't say that *on* and *in* are interchangeable here.

Note also that the first group all say 'on *this* game'. In Britain, *on the game* is a slang term for 'working as a prostitute', so you need to be a bit careful how you use it.

Comment: Person A: He says his mother was on the stage. Person B: On the game more like.